# Cannot serialize non-str key error with a function in async that did not have an issue when it was synchronous

Tags: python, api, serialization, bytecode, kucoin

I have an api request function that works properly. My signature serializes fine, and the api request will go through, but the moment i turn this in to an asynchronous function it gives me a serializing issue somewhere that is genuinely unaffected by the asynchronicity of the function.

I get: #Signature-Cannot serialize non-str key b'aQbzHhquttFv+Kpd9TNkTHOmNy183ybJZTEP8PoDJyQ=

```
async def kucoin_order(pair,side,amount):#Signature-Cannot serialize non-str key b'aQbzHhquttFv+Kpd9TNkTHOmNy183ybJZTEP8PoDJyQ='
    kucoin_balance,api_key, api_secret, api_passphrase = {},settings_feed['kucoin_key'], settings_feed['kucoin_secret'], settings_feed['kucoin_quote']
    timestamp = str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
    data = {"clientOid": timestamp,"side": side,"symbol": pair,"type": "market","size": amount}
    data_json = json.dumps(data)
    str_to_sign = str(timestamp) + 'POST' + '/api/v1/orders' + data_json
    signature=base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'),str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha256).digest())
    passphrase=base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'),api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha256).digest())
    headers = {"KC-API-SIGN": signature,#Cannot serialize non-str key b'aQbzHhquttFv+Kpd9TNkTHOmNy183ybJZTEP8PoDJyQ='
               "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(timestamp),
               "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
               "KC-API-PASSPHRASE":passphrase,
               "KC-API-KEY-VERSION":"2",
               "Content-Type":"application/json"}
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            assets = await session.post(f"https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/orders",headers = headers, data = data_json)
            if not assets.status == 200:raise Exception('Status code not 200')
            assets = await assets.json()
            if 'status' in assets and assets['status'] == 'error': raise Exception('Status code not 200')
            if debug: print('Kucoin order for', pair, assets)
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data_json).json()
        print(response.json())
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

I've tried different variations of the encoding of bytecode for the signature to no avail. So even if you don't have an api key/pass, you can still see it won't encode it properly. There is no returning bad, just that it won't encode it properly.

Answer (score 2):

`aiohttp` doesn't automatically convert bools and bytes to a string in the headers, params, etc. dictionaries. Do it yourself.

```py
async def kucoin_order(pair,side,amount):
    kucoin_balance,api_key, api_secret, api_passphrase = {},settings_feed['kucoin_key'], settings_feed['kucoin_secret'], settings_feed['kucoin_quote']
    timestamp = str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
    data = {"clientOid": timestamp,"side": side,"symbol": pair,"type": "market","size": amount}
    data_json = json.dumps(data)
    str_to_sign = str(timestamp) + 'POST' + '/api/v1/orders' + data_json
    signature=base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'),str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha256).digest())
    passphrase=base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'),api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha256).digest())
    headers = {"KC-API-SIGN": signature.decode('utf-8'),  # Add .decode('utf-8')
               "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(timestamp),
               "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
               "KC-API-PASSPHRASE":passphrase,
               "KC-API-KEY-VERSION":"2",
               "Content-Type":"application/json"}
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            assets = await session.post(f"https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/orders",headers = headers, data = data_json)
            if not assets.status == 200:raise Exception('Status code not 200')
            assets = await assets.json()
            if 'status' in assets and assets['status'] == 'error': raise Exception('Status code not 200')
            if debug: print('Kucoin order for', pair, assets)
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data_json).json()
        print(response.json())
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```